# copy a table from one Sheet and paste it in the next empty row of another Sheet using VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy and paste a table from one Sheet to another Sheet in the next empty row. The problem is that my code doesn't search the next empty row. it gives me always the first row as the empty one.

this is my Code:

```
Sub AddToPriceSummary()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
lastrow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

copySheet.Range("A2:AS10").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So here `lastrow` is always 1

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lastrow` is not qualified with `pasteSheet`.

Try:

```
lastrow = pasteSheet.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
```

A safer way to find the `lastrow`using the `Find` function :

```
lastrow = pasteSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=pasteSheet.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Comment: It doesn't work. lastrow has always 1 and the table is pasted starting from row 1.

Comment: @Moez try edited code for a more relable way using the `Find` function